# Openweathermap API get HIGH and LOW temperature of the day

Tags: android, openweathermap

I'm developing an android app and I need the current weather and its low/high temperature for the city I'm in. Is there a way to get the current high and low temperature for the city I'm in?

I found that there's a min/max temperature but I don't think it's what I'm looking for. If openweathermap doesn't have low/high temp, is there a way I can find it manually from its data?

"Please, do not confuse min/max parameters in current weather API and forecast API. In current weather API temp_min and temp_max are optional parameters mean min / max temperature in the city at the current moment to see deviation from current temp just for your reference. For large cities and megalopolises geographically expanded it might be applicable. In most cases both temp_min and temp_max parameters have the same volume as 'temp'. Please, use temp_min and temp_max parameters in current weather API optionally."

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I don't believe we did, the best thing to do would be to just use a different weather API that provides high and low temperature of the day..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Current Weather API of OpenWeatherMap the max and min temp are based on the current temperature. Meaning if the temp is 70 degrees the min is probably 69 degrees and the max is 71 degrees. The min and max are just given to be the range of temperature at that time not the entire day. You must use the other API (Forecast API) to get the min and max temperatures of the ENTIRE day.

Answer (score 4):

> If openweathermap doesn't have low/high temp, is there a way I can find it manually from its data?

### If you're on a free OpenWeatherMap plan

You can approximate the daily minimum/maximum temperatures using 24 hours of data from the [5 days/3 hour forecast API](https://openweathermap.org/forecast5):

1. Call the API as needed.
2. Iterate over the first 8 three-hour `list` records, capturing `main.temp` and keeping track of the lowest and highest values seen.

It's possible that the actual, real minimum and/or maximum temperature could occur somewhere around the midpoint of two readings; as such, the calculations reached above can be marginally off.  Nonetheless, this approach has been very sufficient for my needs in practice.

### If you're on any paid OpenWeatherMap plan

You can get daily minimum/maximum temperatures from the [daily forecast API](https://openweathermap.org/forecast16).

Answer (score 0):

Further to what @SonneyStarPLUS said (from their web site):

Please, do not confuse min/max parameters in our weather APIs.

In Hourly forecast API, Current weather API and 5 day / 3 hour forecast API - temp_min and temp_max are optional parameters mean min / max temperature in the city at the current moment to see deviation from current temp just for your reference. For large cities and megalopolises geographically expanded it might be applicable. In most cases both temp_min and temp_max parameters have the same volume as 'temp'. Please, use temp_min and temp_max parameters in current weather API optionally.
In 16 Day forecast - min and max mean maximum and minimum temperature in the day.